# Compiled kernel stuck on "loading initial ramdisk"

Tags: compilation, linux-kernel, archlinux

I've a modified version of kernel 5.6.0, I followed the instructions showed [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel/Traditional_compilation) to compile and to install it. The process goes well, but when I boot my compiled kernel, the screen freezes on "Loading initial ram disk", I found the same problem [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=177307), but there is no answer to the question. I would like to know how to solve this problem, I've already tried to compile the kernel on different distros but all of them be stuck at the same screen.

Comment: The initial ramdisk needs to include all the code necessary to find and mount the root filesystem.  For example, if the root filesystem is on a logical volume on a RAID device, it might need to include the kernel module for md, mdraid10, lvm, and for the disk controller.  There is usually an option to drop to a single-user mode shell on error for debug purposes.  You also need to make sure that your console is supported in the initrd. https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/initrd.html